# What attributes are not necessary in inline-SVG code

Tags: html, svg, attributes

I am working on a project that generates super strong passwords (for practise).

When using inline SVG, I was just wondering if there are any unnecessary attributes to the SVG code, because I'm trying to make it as short as possible.

In this specific snippet, I have a copy-to-clipboard icon.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 488.3 488.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 488.3 488.3;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M314.25,85.4h-227c-21.3,0-38.6,17.3-38.6,38.6v325.7c0,21.3,17.3,38.6,38.6,38.6h227c21.3,0,38.6-17.3,38.6-38.6V124
            C352.75,102.7,335.45,85.4,314.25,85.4z M325.75,449.6c0,6.4-5.2,11.6-11.6,11.6h-227c-6.4,0-11.6-5.2-11.6-11.6V124
            c0-6.4,5.2-11.6,11.6-11.6h227c6.4,0,11.6,5.2,11.6,11.6V449.6z"/>
        <path d="M401.05,0h-227c-21.3,0-38.6,17.3-38.6,38.6c0,7.5,6,13.5,13.5,13.5s13.5-6,13.5-13.5c0-6.4,5.2-11.6,11.6-11.6h227
            c6.4,0,11.6,5.2,11.6,11.6v325.7c0,6.4-5.2,11.6-11.6,11.6c-7.5,0-13.5,6-13.5,13.5s6,13.5,13.5,13.5c21.3,0,38.6-17.3,38.6-38.6
            V38.6C439.65,17.3,422.35,0,401.05,0z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Well in the first step you could erase all empty `<g></g>`.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I mean specifically the ones in the <svg> tag.

Comment: Well, if you dont use the `id` in any formt to identify the svg you can safely drop that.
You can drop the comment line above the svg itself too.

Comment: I am using the `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with what is generally superfluous:

- `version="1.1"` is not interpreted by any browser or renderer I know of.
- `style="enable-background:new 0 0 488.3 488.3;"` While setting a style attribute in general might be good idea, the property `enable-background` is [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#AccessBackgroundImage) and was never implemented anywhere

The following might or might not have their place, depending on circumstances:

- `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` must be the first line of a XML-conforming standalone SVG. Note the encoding is not the default `utf-8`. If the SVG is used inline in HTML, browsers just ignore the line (if it is not the first line of the document), but strictly speaking its use in any other place breaks XML-wellformedness.
- `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` Defining a namespace is only needed if you really have an element/attribute somewhere that uses it, for example a `<use xlink:href="..." />`. Even then, most browsers nowadays support the namespace-less `href`.
- `xml:space="preserve"` is only usefull if you have `<text>` elements with `<tspan>` children. It will then govern whether whitespace between those child tags is interpreted as a space character.
- `x="0px" y="0px"` On an outermost `<svg>` element in a standalone file, x and y are always ignored. If the SVG is embedded inline in other content, values other than the default 0 might have an effect, depending on the host language. (In HTML, you'll probably have to use CSS `top` and `left` instead.)

And finally, what is missing:

- `width` and `height` have a default of `150px` and `100px` when the SVG is used inline. (For standalone files, the `viewBox` values will be used when they are missing.)
- `preserveAspectRatio` has a default of `xMidYMid meet`. It defines how the `viewBox` is fitted into the SVGs dimensions if the aspect ratio of  `width`, `height` and `viewBox` do not match.

Comment: For standalone, no. For embedding in HTML, per spec it can be left out. But I am not so sure about implementations, so I tend to leave it in. Point in case: if you append an element from the SVG namespace with Javascript to a HTML DOM, you still need to use `.setAttributeNS()`.

Comment: Argh! That should have read: For standalone, yes it is neccessary. See https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#Namespace

Comment: SVG width and height do not have a default of 100% when width and height are missing. They are 150px x 100px (standard default of replaced elements)